# how to store Query in zend registry (ZF)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I want to store mysql query in zend registry because i have one action and that is calling through ajax but in 2 different ways.

1= when java script event occur.  that is

```
  $("#show_history_call_logs").click(function(){
   var pass = true;
   var start_date    = $("#start_date").val();
   var end_date      = $("#end_date").val();
   var page_to_get   = $('input[name=hidden]').val();

 //some validation

  if(pass == true){
var href= "http://localhost/abc/xyz/index.php/login/"+page_to_get+"/";
var data ='start_date=' + start_date + '&end_date=' + end_date + '&option_call_log=' + option_call_log + '&option_call_log_asc_desc=' + option_call_log_asc_desc;
 $.ajax({ type: "GET",
       url: href,
      data: data,
      success: function(response){
       $('#paged-data-container').html(response);
        }
       });
       return false;
    }
```

the above code takes values from elements call my action and make query according.
this work fine

2 = when (zend paginator in my action )pagination links clicks.
the problem is here when i click any pagination so certainly its calling the same action and its not getting the values i passsed it through ajax  call so its giving error for that i changed my code like this

```
 $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();  
 $start_date = $this->_getParam('start_date');
$end_date = $this->_getParam('end_date');
$option_call_log = $this->_getParam('option_call_log');
$option_call_log_asc_desc = $this->_getParam('option_call_log_asc_desc');

if(empty($start_date) && empty($end_date) && empty($option_call_log) && empty($option_call_log_asc_desc)){
                 //$select =  $registry->get('select');
                 $select = Zend_Registry::get('select');
                }
                 else{
    if(empty($end_date) || $end_date == ""){
        $select = $DB->select()
             ->from('CALL_LOG', array('caller_name','call_number','call_start_time','call_duration','call_direction'))
            ->where('phone_service_id = ?', $phone_service_id)
            ->where("date_created >= ?",  $start_date_formatted)
            ->order("".$option_call_log." ".$option_call_log_asc_desc);

            Zend_Registry::set('select',$select);
        }
        else{
            $select = $DB->select()
             ->from('CALL_LOG', array('caller_name','call_number','call_start_time','call_duration','call_direction'))
            ->where('phone_service_id = ?', $phone_service_id)
            ->where("date_created >= ?",  $start_date_formatted)
            ->where("date_created <= ?",  $end_date_formatted)
            ->order("".$option_call_log." ".$option_call_log_asc_desc);

            Zend_Registry::set('select',$select);
        }
                 }
```

firstly it will not come to to first IF statement so there i am storing my query in registry and when pagination links click so there will not set my 4 variables anf first IF statement will execuated so i ll get what i stored in registry.
but in that case its giving me the error which is

```
Message: No entry is registered for key 'select'
```

any 1 please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `Zend_Registry` keeps its values only until the current request has finished. If you set the value in one request and want to retrieve it in another one, you should use [`Zend_Session`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.html) instead.

Hope that helps,

Comment: what i wanted its working now but after some time means may be session expire so its not doing  .is there a way that make it persistant ??

Comment: You might play a bit with the rememberMe() method of Zend_Session, to make it expire later. More details here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html